# Python-requests + Django changing the parameters structure in URL

Tags: python, django, python-requests

Basicly, I've done with Python-requests and Django search feature through Google Books API with single **q** parameter (as shown in link below)

https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#WorkingVolumes

and after submiting form I'm getting list of dicts in json as I want with this single parameter, and I'm getting in json data where appers keyword "Hobbit" and URL looks like this

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api?books=hobbit

but when I'm trying to add special keywords provided by Google Books API like,
**intitle, inauthor, inpublisher, subject**, etc.

and trying to search for it I'm getting URL

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api?books=hobbit**&**intitle**=&**inauthor**=&**inpublisher**=&**isbn**=&**lccn**=&**oclc**=**

which only returns the data of single **q** parameter, because the correct URL for special keywords in Google Books API looks like this

https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers**+**inauthor**:**keyes**+**subject**:**somesubject

So as you see then correct URL got signs

**+** against **&** and **:** against **=**

so the Correct URL that I want to get would look like this

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api?books=hobbit**+**intitle**:something+**inauthor**:something+**inpublisher**:something+**isbn**:something+**lccn**:something+**oclc**:something**

My question is how to change this structure to correct as Google books API require?

Tried to find this in python-requests docs but there are nothing about this

views.py

```py
def api(request):
    books = {
        'intitle': 'intitle',
        'inauthor': 'inauthor',
        'inpublisher': 'inpublisher',
        'subject': 'subject',
        'isbn': 'isbn',
        'lccn': 'lccn',
        'oclc': 'oclc'
    }
    if 'books' in request.GET:
        books = request.GET['books']
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%s' % books
        response = requests.get(url)
        books = response.json()
        print(type(books))
        with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
            json.dump(books, write_file)

    return render(request, 'books/api.html', {'books': books})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to construct the query string manually. Assuming that your request will look like http://127.0.0.1:8000/api?books=hobbit&intitle=a&inauthor=b&inpublisher=c, you can construct the query string like this:

```
def api(request):
    # ...
    if 'books' in request.GET:
        books = request.GET['books']
        query_dict = request.GET.copy()
        del query_dict['books']
        query = '+'.join([books, *['{}:{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in query_dict.items()]])
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=' + query
        # ...
```

The final google query requires *books* as the first parameter. So, we need to extract the *books* value from `request.GET`. Now, to get all other values, we need to delete the *books* key. But, `request.GET` is a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) object, which is immutable. To convert it into a mutable object, `request.GET.copy()` can be used (which creates a mutable **copy**).

Comment: Hey @Keyur, my request actually right now looks like this what but what I want is to change every sign & to + and every = to :

Comment: When you submit a form, you will get url like I mentioned in my answer. Rather than changing the url itself, it is easy to construct to required string using the url.

Comment: Ok but can you explain usage of copy? I don't understand it

Comment: Added explanation in the answer.

Comment: 1 more thin that confusing me is how to use it with render function?

Comment: The rest of the code will remain the same. What you've done should work.